# Cannot Resolve symbol 'CallbackToFutureAdapter' in ListenableWorker

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-workmanager

I am implementing a ListenableWorker class according to [this official documentation from google](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/listenableworker)

I am getting the following error Cannot resolve symbol 'CallbackToFutureAdapter'

Below is the method i am trying to implement

```
return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture(completer -> {
            Callback callback = new Callback() {
                int successes = 0;

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    completer.setException(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                    ++successes;
                    if (successes == 100) {
                        completer.set(Result.success());
                    }
                }
            };

            completer.addCancellationListener(cancelDownloadsRunnable, executor);

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
                downloadAsynchronously("https://www.example.com", callback);
            }
            return callback;
        });
```

what should i import to resolve CallbackToFutureAdapter i already have Android X implemented in my app level gradle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add the following import:

```
implementation "androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0"
```

As per documentation [AndroidX Concurrent libraries](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/concurrent#declaring_dependencies)